# Download-Path in URL: Is it secure and how to fix it?

Tags: spring, security, url

I am looking at legacy code in Spring and I'm not sure, if this code is secure. Based on a URL, a HTML page can be downloaded. The original Download-URL is provided by the server, but of course could be modified by the client. There are no additional security meassures like Spring-Security or other path contraints. The controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{subFolder}/download/{filename}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                     @PathVariable("subFolder") String subFolder, @PathVariable("filename") String filename) {
    if (!filename.endsWith(".html")) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(BAD_REQUEST, "Can only download html files.");
    }
    try {
        String filePath = "/path/to/MainFolder/" + subFolder + "/" + filename;
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("file:" + filePath);
        response.setContentType("application/html");
        response.setContentLength((int) resource.contentLength());
        FileCopyUtils.copy(resource.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(NOT_FOUND, "File not found.");
    }
}
```

Although it looks vulnerable, I do not see a hack to exploid.

- Is it possible to leave the `MainFolder`?
- Is it possible to download a not `HTML`-file from the folder?
- Is there a better/more secure way to implement this functionality? (Without security meassures on the file system itself)

Answer (score 1):

This code has at least one issue I can spot, that is [Path Traversal](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal). Since you don't validate the subfolder path variable it can easily go out of main folder by starting with something with `../`. When providing downloads you should never rely on user input for system calls, if possible, and validate user data when you have to accept it restricting it to only known good values (whitelisting), don't try to sanitize the data.